# Gradle - Android APK Split by density - Exclude certain folders for certain densities

Tags: java, android, c++, gradle, apk

Is it possible to exclude certain folders (outside of the res or drawable folder) for certain densities? I've got an assets folder with all kinds of graphics and other files.

They're getting loading by a game engine at runtime in C++. I can't really move them into the res folder without rewriting parts of the engine which I want to avoid.

This is what I have so far in my gradle file:

```
splits {
    density {
      enable true
      exclude "ldpi"
      compatibleScreens 'small', 'normal', 'large', 'xlarge'
   }
}
```

Now in case of mdpi I want to exclude /assets/2048p and /assets/2732p for example. In case of hdpi I would exclude /assets/2732p and /assets/1334p and so on.

Comment: I don't believe that there is an automatic way of doing that. It's conceivable that you could find a way to hook some custom Gradle task in that gets invoked for each split that would see what the split is for and remove stuff from the APK's assets before signing.

Comment: In my extended google sessions before I asked this question I've seen people increase version codes via gradle scripting for each split and I was wondering if it's also possible to delete folders inside the APK. Do you know how that would possibly work?

Comment: While I have created custom Gradle tasks, I have never tried getting control on a per-split basis and I have never tried manipulating the contents of the APK directly. So, while this is conceivably possible, I have no idea if it can really be implemented, let alone the details -- sorry!

Comment: What should be possible is to do your APK trimming after the build. Given a signed APK, you can delete the signature data, delete the assets that you want to get rid of, then re-sign and re-zipalign the APK. I haven't messed with this recently, and so I don't have a current recipe, but I used to do this as part of publishing the APK edition of my book (though in my case I was making other changes to the APK, not deleting assets).

Comment: Okay both seems viable then, thanks. The first version would be cooler of course - not having to manually mess with the APK after the build. I'll ask google some more, or maybe somebody else in the SOF universe knows how to ;)

Comment: @CommonsWare Do you by chance know if it's possible to split over the actual physical screen size and not over the density? Our game's textures are made for specific physical screen sizes and just get scaled no matter what the DPI is, so that would make much more sense for us. I've seen that the default android screen size splitting works in dp and not in px, so it's also dpi dependant.

Comment: "Do you by chance know if it's possible to split over the actual physical screen size and not over the density?" -- I do not believe that is possible, sorry. Leastways, it wasn't the last time I checked. The only splits were on density and CPU architecture.